# why some imports cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lucene

I'm new to java , i tried to use word net for senitment analysis .
when i used class of wordnet , i got the following failure in importing

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Deactivate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishMinimalStemmer;
import org.apache.stanbol.commons.stanboltools.datafileprovider.DataFileListener;
import org.apache.stanbol.commons.stanboltools.datafileprovider.DataFileTracker;
import org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.sentiment.api.LexicalCategoryClassifier;
import org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.sentiment.api.SentimentClassifier;
import org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.sentiment.util.WordSentimentDictionary;
import org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.nlp.pos.LexicalCategory;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
```

all the above imports cannot be resolved like `org.apache.felix` , `org.apache.lucene` ,`org.apache.stanbol`,`org.osgi`

[image]

Comment: Are they in your project structure? Class path?

Comment: how can i check for this ?

Comment: If you are actually relying on Maven, and have the Eclipse Maven plug-ins (m2e) installed, you would add the dependency to your pom.xml file. Otherwise, in what sort of environment is this supposed to run? I see mentions of Maven, but also of OSGI,

Comment: thanks , yes it's maven project but i searched in google before posting problem here for how to add them in pom but couldn't find the structure . can you help me for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your compiler is not able to find the necessary packages and or libraries that are needed to resolve these imports. These packages must be included in your class path. For example all of the errors regarding

```
org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.x
```

can be resolved after downloading the latest .jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.scr.annotations/1.11.0

Follow these steps to include jar files in your class path.
     -

- Drag the required jar file from your download directory to the src
  directory of your project in eclipse
- Right click on the jar file, Select *Build Path* and then select Add To Build Path option.
- A dialogue box will appear asking you to link all files in the jar file, just stick with the defaults and hit OK.
- You are done now, all your errors regarding imports will be resolved.

Comment: thanks. it worked for felix so will search for lucene ,stanbol ,osgi in https://mvnrepository.com/ ?

Comment: Glad it helps you :), yeah just search maven repository, if it doesn't return you your required library just search for the same in Google.

Answer (score 1):

These packages need to be within the compiler's class path.

Another way to say it : the compiler needs to be able to know where to find these files. This imposes several constraints:

- these files need to actually exist in your hard drive (whether added manually, or automatically by a dependency manager)
- they should be organized in folders that match the parts of the package name
- the folder where they are must be within the class path, which can be specified with the 'classpath' compiler option, or in your IDE's options

Comment: thanks , but how can i get the files for them ? can i add dependency in pom file or just add files for them ?

Comment: Both options are possible, but adding to the PoM file is simpler. I have added details in my answer

Comment: thanks i searched in google before posting problem here for how to add them in pom but couldn't find the structure . can you help me for that  ?

Comment: I would love to but this will have to be in a different question as the policy on stackoverflow is one problem one question. So please mark this answer as accepted, ask another question and send me the link to that question.