# Maven - incomplete build path

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I wanted to make my first Maven spring application. I have started it by creating new maven application using spring-mvc-archetype as a new project.

After creating project I receive error:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry. Fix the build path then try building this project The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry. Fix the build path then try building this project
```

I am checking `project -> build paths -> configure build paths -> Libralies -> Maven dependencies` and there is no class file with that name.

Can you guys help me repair my build paths to not to receive this error?

Comment: Could you show us the generated POM?

Comment: add your org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry jar file in your buildpath. See my answer on the question in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688536/why-some-imports-cannot-be-resolved/39688714#39688714
Hope this resolves your issue

Comment: @AnusKaleem That is not a good approach. He already uses Maven inside Eclipse. So the correct step is to declare a dependency in the POM and then let the M2E plugin do its job. No need to manually add anything to the build path.

Answer (score 0):

This class is available in  [spring-context](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/format/FormatterRegistry.java)

Add the following dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
 <version>your spring version</version>
</dependency>
```